# Using Pivot in SQL t

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I rarely have had to use pivot in SQL and am having trouble wrapping my head around it. I have query that produces a table of patients and insurance for a medical facility. I want to return a single row that shows all of the insurances that the patient has.

Sample data:

```
ID  Insurance
1840    Medicaid Of New York
1841    Affinity Health Plan
1841    Medicaid Of New York
1842    Fidelis Care
1842    Medicaid Of New York
```

The goal is to show the data like this:

[image]

I'm understand the basic functionality of pivot, but don't have a lot of time to figure out how to achieve the results above. I haven't achieved anything close to working results, which could be either lack of experience or fatigue at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Ok done. It must be the mental fatigue I'm experiencing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this

```
with data as (
select id,insurance ,row_number() over ( partition by id order by insurance) rowid 
)


select d.id , [1] as ins1,[2] ins2,[3]ins3,[4] ins4
from data d
pivot 
(max(insurance) 
for rowid in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
)pv
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer conditional aggregation where possible:

```
SELECT  ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN INSURANCE ELSE '' END) AS INSURANCE1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN INSURANCE ELSE '' END) AS INSURANCE2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN INSURANCE ELSE '' END) AS INSURANCE3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN INSURANCE ELSE '' END) AS INSURANCE4
FROM (
      SELECT  ID,
              INSURANCE,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY INSURANCE) RN
      FROM YourTable
     ) A
GROUP BY ID
```

[This](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/) is a good read on conditional aggregration, or Cross Tabs, versus `PIVOT`

Answer (score 1):

If you have at most two values (as suggested by your sample data and results), you can use `min()` and `max()`:

```
select id,
       min(insurance) as insurance1,
       (case when min(insurance) <> max(insurance) then max(insurance)
        end) as insurance2
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: There can be up to 4, but I tried to keep the sample data simple to understand how pivot would work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for. This will flatten your records as desired.

```
SELECT 
    ID, Insurance1, Insurance2, Insurance3, Insurance4
FROM (  SELECT 
            ID, 
            Insurance,
            RN = 'Insurance' + 
            CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Insurance) AS CHAR(1))
        FROM MyDB.MySchema.MyTable
) AS d
PIVOT(
    MAX(Insurance) 
        for RN 
            in (Insurance1, Insurance2, Insurance3, Insurance4)
) AS p;
```